# Most efficient way of copying a "hex array" string to a buffer?

Tags: node.js

I'm receiving a high volume of "hex array" strings in the form:

```
'16 03 03 00 50 40 f2 12 71 0b c0 4f 99 dc 87 6f'
```

What's the most efficient way of copying them into an existing, larger buffer?

I'm guessing the naive way would be:

```
var lineBuffer = new Buffer(line.replace(/\s+/g, ''), 'hex');
lineBuffer.copyTo(mainBuffer, offset);
offset += 16;
```

I'm wary of using `line[index]` and doing the simple bit shift and sum, because `string[index]` just resolves to another string.

Comment: Careful with using `.replace(' ', '')`, that will only remove the first instance of `' '`. You probably want `str.replace(/\s+/g, '');` or something similar. I can't speak to its performance, though. Also, you should make sure you're using `new Buffer(str, 'hex');`, so the new buffer knows what encoding your string is in.

Comment: @dvlsg thank you, I've edited my answer with your suggestions. My JS  is rusty and I didn't actually test the code. The reason for the 'existing' buffer is that I'm "appending" these byte hex lines together.

Comment: Fair enough. Using `.write(hexString, startPosition, 'hex')` or `Buffer.concat([ existingBuffer, newBuffer ])` (once you have the new buffer from the hex string) is probably your best bet, then.  I imagine the `concat` solution will make an entirely new `Buffer`, though, if memory usage is still a concern.

Comment: Also, if you're 100% sure that's the format you'll be receiving, using `/ /g` instead of `/\s+/g` was about a 10-20% performance increase in my benchmarks.

Comment: @dvslg thank you! I think that `write` overload was what I was looking for. Could you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

To move this out of the comments,

The solution you're looking for is probably something like this:

```
const line = '16 03 03 00 50 40 f2 12 71 0b c0 4f 99 dc 87 6f';
const regex = / /g;
const encoding = 'hex';
const replacement = '';
function getHexString(input) {
  return input.replace(regex, replacement);
}
const existingBuffer = Buffer.alloc(1024); // just as an example
const offset = existingBuffer.length; // or wherever you need them to go.
function write(buffer, str, pos) {
  const hexString = getHexString(str);
  buffer.write(hexString, pos, encoding);
}
write(existingBuffer, line, 0);
```

I can get about `1,600,000 ops/sec` through benchmark.js with `() => write(existingBuffer, line, 0)`. Cheating a bit, since I'm constantly writing to position `0` instead of appending, but it should be close enough to get you an idea. The closest I could come with other combinations I was trying was about `1,200,000 ops/sec`.

Also as a side note, I would strongly suggest using `Buffer.alloc()` wherever you are creating your original buffer, if you aren't. You can also use `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` which is faster, but that may leave non-zero data in the buffer. Which may be okay, if you know you're going to fill the entire buffer with new data before using it (or are only using known-filled slices). More reading [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_from_buffer_alloc_and_buffer_allocunsafe).